# How do you say "wake up" to someone who is not sleeping but fainted?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example:

> *Adam faints.* *Steve goes there and tries to **(wake up?)** him.*

What do you do with someone who fainted?

Comment: A thesaurus will help here.

Comment: and smelling salts!

Comment: @lbf or a smack in the face...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [*revive*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/revive):

> **re·vive** *v.* re·vived, re·viv·ing, re·vives
>   **v.tr.**
>   1. To bring back to life or consciousness; resuscitate: *revived the passenger who fainted.*